# $E_n$-space and n-connected pointed space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

Is it true that the homotopy category of group-like $E_n$-spaces is equivalent to the homotopy category of pointed $n$-connected spaces ? If it is true, what should be the statement  when $"n\rightarrow \infty"$ ?

By $n$-connected space $X$, I mean that $\pi_{i}X=0$ for $0\leq i\leq n-1$.

**Edit**

***Notions***: The $\infty$-category of group-like $E_n$-spaces is denoted by $\mathbf{G}_{n}$ 
The category of pointed $n$-connected spaces is denoted by $\mathbf{Top}_{n}$.
As Peter May and Ring Spectra noticed,  $$Bar^{n}:\mathbf{G}_{n}\longrightarrow \mathbf{Top}_{n}:\Omega^{n}$$
is an $\infty$-equivalence. It seems very natural that the homotpy limit 
$$ holim(\dots \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbf{G}_{n}\rightarrow\dots \mathbf{G}_{1})$$
is the $\infty$-category of group-like $E_{\infty}$-spaces i.e. connective spectra. 
My question is the following:

How can we see that

$$ holim(\dots \rightarrow \mathbf{Top}_{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbf{Top}_{n}\rightarrow\dots \mathbf{Top}_{1})$$ is naturally equivalent to the $\infty$-category of connective spectra without using $E_{n}-spaces$?

PS: As Peter May noticed there is a problem with the my definition  of $n$-connectivity. But I think the idea is clear.

Comment: It is true and the statement for n=$\infty $ says that there is an equivalence of group-like $E_\infty $ spaces and connective spectra. See May's "The geometry of iterated loop spaces" for the precise statements and proofs

Comment: To address your edit: this is going to depend on what exactly is your definition of spectrum. As far as I can tell in the classical definition a connective spectrum is defined as an element of that limit (that is a sequence of pointed spaces $\{X_n\}$ with $X_n$ (n-1)-connected and equivalences $X_n\to \Omega X_{n+1}$).

Comment: @Max I have accordingly edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Denis and ``Ring Spectra'', thanks for the references.  I did not treat
non-connected spaces in "The geometry of iterated loop spaces", which is why
you couldn't find that there. It should have been treated in the immediate sequel 
"$E_{\infty}$ spaces, group completions, and permutative categories",
but that perversely and for no good mathematical reason restricts to the
case $n=\infty$.  The proof works the same way in general.  Max, $n$-connected
means $\pi_i = 0$ for $i\leq n$ (you can look it up on Wikipedia if you do not 
believe me; this is implicit in Ring Spectra's answer).

Briefly, the essential point is to start with an $E_n$-space $X$ and construct
from it an $n-1$-connected space $Y_n(X)$ and a natural map $X\longrightarrow \Omega^n Y_n(X)$ 
that  is a weak equivalence if $X$ is connected and a group completion in general,
hence a weak equivalence if $\pi_0(X)$ is a group.  Conversely, if $Y$ is an
$n-1$-connected space, then of course $X=\Omega^n Y$ is a grouplike $E_n$-space.
With the construction of Geo, $Y_n(X) = B(\Sigma^n, C_n, X)$ where $C_n$ is the monad
associated to an $E_n$-operad.  The group completion property for $n\geq 2$ follows
from the group completion property for the natural map 
$\alpha_n\colon C_nX \longrightarrow \Omega^n \Sigma^n X$ (which I didn't 
yet know how to prove when I wrote Geo, but did thanks to work of Fred Cohen when I wrote the cited sequel).
The case $n=1 is classical and special.

Answer (score 1):

When n=∞, this states that the homotopy category of infinite loop spaces is equivalent to the homotopy category of connective spectra; see *The geometry of iterated loop spaces* by May.

We can also prove this statement in the general case. Let X be a (pointed) n-connected space; then the loop space Ω<sup>n+1</sup>X is an E<sub>n+1</sub>-space, and this is easily checked to be grouplike. So if **nConnTop** and **A<sub>n</sub>** are the categories of n-connective spaces and E<sub>n+1</sub>-spaces, respectively, then the (n+1)-fold loop space functor Ω<sup>n+1</sup> induces an equivalence of categories between **nConnTop** and **A<sub>n</sub>**. (I believe the statement for E<sub>n+1</sub>-spaces in general should be somewhere in May's book; I can't find it, though.)

One implication of this, using the Freudenthal suspension theorem, is that if a homotopy n-type has the structure of a grouplike E<sub>n+2</sub>-space, then it canonically has the structure of an E<sub>∞</sub>-space, which is a special case of the Baez-Dolan stablization hypothesis. (See [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories/5789), for example.)

RE your edit: a connective spectrum is usually defined as an object of the homotopy limit of the sequence ...→Top<sub>n+1</sub>→Top<sub>n</sub>→...→Top<sub>1</sub>. (See also Denis's comment on your question.)